# python 'pip' has no attribute 'main'

Tags: attributes, pip, program-entry-point, importerror, python-3.6

I have been looking all over for a solution. I found one question asking something similar to this, but they were doing it inside of python(which I also tried) and the answers didn't work. So please don't be mad; nothing seems to work!

I've been having a lot of troubles with pip. I am on windows 10, python 3.6. First it wouldn't let me install scipy no matter what I did, so I uninstalled it and reinstalled. get-pip.py wouldn't work, so I reinstalled python and had it put pip in my path. Now no matter what I try I get:

ImportError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'

Pip is in my path, just like it used to be. I was going to uninstall it again, but because it has no 'main' pip uninstall pip also says it does not have 'main'. I've tried to fix the path, reinstall pip, reinstall python, use easy_install instead, and I am stuck. I have no idea how to uninstall pip at this point. Sorry if this is basic!

I am so lost. I would really appreciate some help! This is a great community! Thanks!! Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score -1):

Check the Scripts directory in your virtual environment home directory. Is there a pip.exe in Scripts? It can be in the path but not installed in the environment itself. You can just copy one from another env Scripts, but make sure it's the right version of pip. DRY